# $H$ $\cong$ $K$ and $G/H$ $\cong$ $G'/K$ implies $G$ $\cong$ $G'$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ and $G'$ be groups not necessarily finite and $H$ and $K$ their subgroups respectively. Given $H$ $\cong$ $K$ and $G/H$ $\cong$ $G'/K$, is it true that $G$ $\cong$ $G'$? Please help me with an explicit map if they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is very false. For the simplest counterexample, take $G = \mathbb{Z}_4$, $G' = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, $H,K \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. In fact, it is in general [extremely hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Extension_problem) to classify all the so-called *extensions* of a group by another.

However, *if there exists* a homomorphism $f:G \to G'$ that restricts to an isomorphism $H \cong K$ and that induces an isomorphism $G/H \cong G'/K$, then $f$ is an isomorphism (this is the [short five lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_five_lemma)).